# How can I prevent automatic redirect in LoggedIn-event on the asp.net login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I prevent the asp login-controls automatic redirect on authentication in the LoggedIn-event? I want to make some controls available to the user before redirect...

Stig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this, however, you could use a custom login rather than the asp:login control using:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

then redirect using `Response.Redirect` or whatever redirect method you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only solutions I've come up with so far. I was hoping there was a easy way out :)

Comment: The login control is really only calling redirectfromloginpage

Comment: In fact, digging into reflector shows that it does this: 

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.UserNameInternal, this.RememberMeSet);
                this.OnLoggedIn(EventArgs.Empty);
                this.Page.Response.Redirect(this.GetRedirectUrl(), false);

Comment: Paul: I'm aware of that but my problem is how do I prevent the control from calling RedirectFromLoginPage... I need to avoid the redirect and only have a postback...

Comment: Guess the only way is to go with the custom login-control